# Trying to calculate txPower

Tags: calculus

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568607/update-refresh-rate-for-monitoring-ibeacons) the distance can be calculated using this:

```
distanceInMeters = 0.89976 * (rssi/txPower)^7.7095 + 0.111
```

Because using iOS, there's no method in getting `txPower`, so I changed the approach and resulting in:

```
1 = 0.89976 * (-47 / txPower)^7.7095 + 0.111
```

But unfortunately I'm not really good in math so I have no idea how to calculate `txPower`. Is there anyone who can help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\eqalign{
1 &= 0.89976 * (-47 / txPower)^{7.7095} + 0.111\cr
1 - 0.111 &= 0.89976 * (-47 / txPower)^{7.7095}\cr
(1 - 0.111)/0.89976 &= (-47 / txPower)^{7.7095}\cr
\ln [(1 - 0.111)/0.89976] &= 7.7095 \ln (-47 / txPower)\cr
\ln [(1 - 0.111)/0.89976] / 7.7095 &= \ln (-47 / txPower)\cr
e^ {\ln [(1 - 0.111)/0.89976] / 7.7095} &= -47 / txPower\cr
txPower &= {-47 \over e^ {\ln [(1 - 0.111)/0.89976] / 7.7095}} = -47.07340169\cr
}$$